# Keep div from going under image with absolute positioning

Tags: html, css, css-position

I want put one image with a caption and after the image a description of the image. When I use absolute positioning for the image, the div goes under the image. How can i fix it so the div goes after the image: http://jsfiddle.net/qhcb0616/

```css
.slide-square {
 width: 148px;
 height: 348px;
    border:solid 1px black;
 background: red;
}

.slide-square img {
 position: absolute;
}

.slide-square h1 {
 position: relative; 
    font-size:11px;
    background :blue;
    text-align:right;
    float:right;
    color:white;
    padding:5px;
    margin-top:5px;
    margin-right:5px;
}

.slide-square div {
 display: inline-block;
 font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="slide-square">
  <img src="http://www.flowers-online.com.au/flower-pictures/spring-surprise-flower-bouquet-b10l.jpg" alt="" width="148" height="148">
  <h1>Scientific</h1>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit debitis error magnam sunt numquam ab quasi omnis eaque dolore, perferendis quisquam, minus qui repudiandae possimus esse tempore ipsum adipisci soluta!</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's how position:Absolute works taking the element out of the flow on the document.... Why you need that if you aren't setting values for position left,right,top or bottom ... or the relative parent ?

Comment: Sorry I'm not getting your problem from your question. Is it the text over spilling the box?

Comment: @Danko I want the caption is on image but the div after the image! u know i mean ?

Comment: You set a height for your container. Take out this height and it will work. If you want it that size add overflow:scroll to your description css to get it all in

Comment: @Creaven i want do this [link](http://s7.postimg.org/86ozg3upn/test.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is make `absolute` the `h1` element. Try this:

Make the parent relative:

```
.slide-square {
  position: relative;
}
```

Then position the `h1` on the parent

```
.slide-square h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 5px;
}
```

<sub>Remove also the absolute for the img</sub>

#### Check the Snippet Below

```css
.slide-square {
  width: 148px;
  height: 348px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
}
.slide-square h1 {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 11px;
  background: blue;
  text-align: right;
  color: white;
  margin:0;
  padding: 5px;
  top: 5px;
  right: 5px;
}
.slide-square div {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="slide-square">
  <img src="http://www.flowers-online.com.au/flower-pictures/spring-surprise-flower-bouquet-b10l.jpg" alt="" width="148" height="148">
  <h1>Scientific</h1>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit debitis error magnam sunt numquam ab quasi omnis eaque dolore, perferendis quisquam, minus qui repudiandae possimus esse tempore ipsum adipisci soluta!</div>
</div>
```